# Javascript return correct value for checkbox using each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to return some amount when user click checkbox and do some calculation.
But the result always return wrong value if i try to check two checkbox.

```
$('.type_checkbox input[type="checkbox"]').each(function (index) {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            checkbox_price_prefix = $(this).data('prefix-checkbox');
            checkbox_price = checkbox_price_prefix + $(this).data('price-checkbox');   // <----- += or =
    }
});
```

You can try [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/ruslyrossi/so7c7xtm/1/)

The problem is when user try to check type A and type B, the result suppose to be RM90

Comment: Not related with question: `var optionCheckbox = function optionCheckbox() {` is awesome.

Comment: And [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/so7c7xtm/5/) from me with rewritten code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not totaling you count - you are replacing it. change:

```
checkbox_price = checkbox_price_prefix + $(this).data('price-checkbox');
```

To:

```
checkbox_price += parseFloat(checkbox_price_prefix + $(this).data('price-checkbox'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are overwritting the variables' value in each loop iteration...

```
var checkbox_price = 0;
$('.type_checkbox input[type="checkbox"]').each(function (index) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        checkbox_price += parseInt($(this).data('prefix-checkbox') + $(this).data('price-checkbox'),10);
    }
});
```

Declaring the variable outside the scope of each, and then increment its value with the values of the checked inbox will do as you want.

And with some jQuery selector optimisation:

```
var checkbox_price = 0;
$('.type_checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function (index) {
        checkbox_price += parseInt($(this).data('prefix-checkbox') + $(this).data('price-checkbox'),10);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems here:

- You are overwriting the total value instead of summing them together
- You cannot get the value `-20` by concatenating the strings `-` and `20`.

You also don't need to check `:checked` on each loop. Just include that in your selector:

```
var optionCheckbox = function optionCheckbox() {
    var totalAdjustment = 0;

    $('.type_checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
        var prefix = $(this).data('prefix-checkbox');
        var price = $(this).data('price-checkbox');
        totalAdjustment += prefix === '-' ? -price : +price;
    });

    return totalAdjustment ;
};
```

Comment: _You cannot get the value -20 by concatenating the strings "-" and "20"_. What about `parseFloat("-" + "20");`, which does exist in original code?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your calculate function

```
 total = 100 + parseFloat(option_checkbox_return);
```

100 must be declared as global variable and initialised to 100

```
var x=100;
var optionCheckbox = function optionCheckbox() {

    var checkbox_price_prefix;
    var checkbox_price = 0;
    // Loop Checkbox
    $('.type_checkbox input[type="checkbox"]').each(function (index) {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            checkbox_price_prefix = $(this).data('prefix-checkbox');
            checkbox_price = checkbox_price_prefix + $(this).data('price-checkbox');
        }
    });

    return checkbox_price;
}

    function calculateTotal() {

        var option_checkbox_return = optionCheckbox();

        total = x + parseFloat(option_checkbox_return);
        x=total;
        result = parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2); // Convert to 2 decimal places
        $('.price_placeholder').html('RM' + result);

    }

$('.type_checkbox input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
    calculateTotal();
});
```

Comment: @Regent i edited my answer and it will works :). i added the js code

Comment: Even though you didn't mention `x = total;` (which is important part of your idea), code is still incorrect. Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/so7c7xtm/6/), showing that it works incorrectly.